# The initial phrase in Mozart's Alla Turca

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-theory

In the initial phrase, if I just saw the melody, I would have been sure that, in the third full measure, the melody switches to (V). Yet the accompaniment stays firmly in (i) and it sounds great. Does this technique have a name and why does it sound so good? Are there any other well-known pieces that do that?

Comment: It could be that it stays in `i` because that makes it sound more like the style of Turkish music that Mozart sought to evoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could go to E7 in bar 3.  But it stays on Am instead.  And all we can really say about that is 'composer's choice'.  Both are fine.   And a few other moves would have been fine too.

This parsimonious use of harmonies is characteristic of early Classical music. The longer you stay on one chord, the more dramatic when you eventually DO use another one - even one as seemingly obvious as a V.   Simple, and clever.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the stubborn keeping of one (often, but not always, bass-) note/harmony against melodies that don't really fit on it is called [pedal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point).

But I definitely would hesitate to call this a pedal. What's actually going on is that Mozart is (arguably, rather bluntly) appropriating the stereotypical “eastern” [double harmonic minor scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_minor_scale), which has a characteristic ♯ⅳ degree whilst clearly being in minor (definitely not Lydian). In fact, notice how the last beat in bar two literally clashes C and E with D♯, which is enharmonic to a minor and major third simultaneously:

```
X:1
L:1/16
M:2/4
K:C
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] z4       (fe"!"^de    | .b2)
[V:B]  (A,2.[C2E2]) .[C2E2].[C2E2] | A,2
```

That's something that doesn't really happen in classical music (ever?).

What happens a lot in classical music though is that sharpened degrees are used as leading notes into another tonic. Specifically here, Mozart is no doubt playing with the listener's expectation that the ♯ⅳ note should lead to the dominant, like

```
X:1
L:1/16
M:2/4
K:C
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] z4       (fe^d2)          | e4
[V:B]  (A,2.[C2E2]) .[C2E2](B,A,) | (^G,2.[B,2D2]) .[B,2D2].[B,2D2]
```

and as you noticed the melody seems to confirm that by going into B·A·G♯, but not really – actually the whole bar 3 acts more like a mere [turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Turn) ornament on the note A, as it were

```
X:1
L:1/16
M:2/4
K:C
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] z4       (fe^f^g)    | !turn!a4 !turn!a4
[V:B]  (A,2.[C2E2]) .[C2E2].[C2E2] | (A,2.[C2E2]) .[C2E2].[C2E2]
```

Comment: Also, most lower neighbors (classically) are half steps below the main note and usually requires the lower note to be sharped. An exception is the lower neighbor to scale step 7. (I've never found that lower neighbor to sound good sharped or not.) A whole step lower neighbor gives a kind modal feel to an ornament.

Comment: You mean ⅵ? That would probably be heard as ♭ⅶ instead.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it can't be ♭ⅶ if it's the lower neighbor of ⅶ.

Comment: "That's something that doesn't really happen in classical music (ever?)": it's not particularly uncommon, but it's also not what's happening here: the harmony is A minor, so it's an augmented fourth and a perfect fifth simultaneously, not a minor and major third. But the augmented fourth arises as a chromatic lower neighbor: an embellishment, not a structural tone. For one part to have such an embellishment while another part holds the structural tone is unremarkable.

Comment: As an example: Bach's cantata BWV 4, *Christ lag in Todesbanden* has, in the second movement (Verse 1), measure 12, at the second half of beat 4, the pitches A2, F#3, D4, E4, A4, and D#5 sounding sumultaneously, the last as a chromatic lower neighbor of E5.

Comment: @phoog the “doesn't...happen in classical” referred to the blue-note interpretation. – Yes, the augmented fourth is perfectly unspectacular, however I disagree about the embellishment bit. A tight chromatism of ♭6-5-♯4 _was_ still something of a weirdness in Mozart's time. Sure, you find tons of that in Tchaikovsky or so, but that was later on. — As for the Bach example: first off, I don't see any D♯ in that bar, are you maybe misreading the original score with all those weird movable C-clefs? –but even if, that's still nothing as overtly pseudo-oriental as what Mozart did in the Rondo.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the D# is in the second violin part, the next to last note (the score I'm reading only uses C clefs for the viola parts). I chose that movement to look for an example because of the violin figure's similar shape to the sonata (with a rest in place of the upper neighbor). But there are plenty of earlier examples of chromatic upper and lower neighbors in close proximity. The first movement of Bach's wedding cantata (202) has more than one example (mm 6-7, m 31). For a Mozart example, see the cadence of the *Rex tremendae* in the *Requiem.*

Answer (score 2):

The melody of the first four bars is firmly based on A minor. Each of the sixteenth-note [turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Turn) starts one note above the main note, and the main notes form an A minor triad. The only slightly unusual note is the D sharp, but that in combination with the F gives the piece the "Turkish" flavor.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The melodic line in the first 4 bars is built on an A minor triad. Here you can see how it appears in the urtext:

[image]

Comment: Good point! And, I've often wondered if Mozart and his contemporaries really played such appogiature _just like a normal sixteenth_. That always seemed silly to me.

Comment: @leftaroundabout they did, in this context.  In some contexts they played it like a normal eighth note. Why do you think it silly?

Comment: They probably wrote it that way to make the harmonic structure clear.

Comment: OP here. This answer makes sense from mostly a theoretical point of view. But from the practical point of view that reflects how the piece is played, the downbeat notes in the third phrase are (leap from an upbeat E)  B G# B G#. If that's not the E chord with some decorations in-between...

Comment: @phoog because then _why not just write a sixteenth_? Although, yeah, “make the harmonic structure clear” is actually a good enough reason. Still – how certain is the historical record actually on this, did they literally recommend to replace the graces with full sixteenths to students?

Comment: @Wynne I don't see how your comment is any less theoretical or more practical than the previous comments. We are all talking theory here -- and there's nothing wrong with that! The LH makes it clear that the chord is still A minor in this bar. In this context, the Bs and G#s are accented non-harmony notes. Just like the earlier Bs, G# and D in the tune.

Comment: @Wynne the figure B-A-G♯-A has A as the center, so the A is quite strong so you do not need to look at it as an E chord.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - The small initial appoggiatura 16th notes (and 8th notes) I've seen, like in the picture, are typically not accented, unlike the usual first notes of beats. Now *that's* a way to interpret this passage....

Comment: @LaurencePayne indeed, I have heard that grace notes were used to avoid violating some rule or other of counterpoint (which probably is roughly the same as "making the harmonic structure clear").

Comment: @leftaroundabout see my previous comment.  As to the historical record, see page five of https://www.google.com/books/edition/Guida_di_musica_being_a_complete_book_of/9m4jsXTuQScC, which was published a year after the sonata in question.  The grace note takes half the value of an undotted note and two thirds of the value of a dotted note (allowing for an engraving error on the explanation of the appoggiatura applied to a quarter note).

Comment: @Dekkadeci on the contrary, because it occurs on the strong part of the beat, an appoggiatura generally *is* supposed to be accented, at least in the 18th century.